# PHP Encoding correction

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have tried all the solutions and I am unable to find a simple fix. There is encoding on this string that I need to remove when I run a utf8_encode on the string this is the output.

[image]

```
<adf><prospect><requestdate>2018-â 07-â 10T10:03:37-â 04:00</â requestdate></prospect></adf>
```

How do I get rid of those special characters?

This is the normal xml string

```
<adf><prospect><requestdate>2018-⁠07-⁠10T10:03:37-⁠04:00</⁠requestdate></prospect></adf>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "low-tech" solution would be to just to replace those hidden characters with `str_replace()`:

```
# Hidden character goes here vv 
echo utf8_encode(str_replace('⁠','','<adf><prospect><requestdate>2018-⁠07-⁠10T10:03:37-⁠04:00</⁠requestdate></prospect></adf>'));
```

Comment: There are a few different ones and due to the requests coming in by email it is hard to target specific chars

Comment: I am going to mark this as the answer as I have no better way do it so I went thise route.